# How do I Convert Func<T, object> to Func<dynamic, object>?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

Given the property:

`Func<dynamic,object> Format { set; get; }`

And a method parameter:

`void SomeMethod(Func<T, object> format) { // Set Format here.. }`

Within this method, how would I set the Format property?

Comment: This is a weird way to do this.  The result will be a function "Format" that takes a dynamic, but will fail if the dynamic cannot be cast to type T.

Comment: Thus, you will need to handle the cases where it cannot cast the dynamic to be of type T inside the //Set format here.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis True that, dynamic should be handled with care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a new function that takes the dynamic object, casts it to the object that you need it to be, and then passes that value to the more specific function that you have:

```
Format = dyn => format((T)dyn);
```